# See if 30 minutes have passed?

Tags: php, mysql

Im selecting the following time from MySQL from a row:

```
2013-02-05 11:05:20
```

I want to see if 30 minutes have passed..

This is what I've tried so far, but cant seem to get it to work:

```
if(strtotime($row['last_visit']) > strtotime("-30 minutes")) {
        $database->query("UPDATE `visit_count` SET visitCount = visitCount + 1, cookieId = '$sid', last_visit='$idag' WHERE cookieId = '$sid' AND ipaddress = '$ip'");

}
```

> last_visit = 2013-02-05 11:05:20 in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compare with cuurrent time

```
if(strtotime($row['last_visit']) < (time() -(30*60)) {
        $database->query("UPDATE `visit_count` SET visitCount = visitCount + 1, cookieId = '$sid', last_visit='$idag' WHERE cookieId = '$sid' AND ipaddress = '$ip'");

}
```

Comment: Still same problem, the counter fires on every load

Answer (score 1):

```
$database->query("UPDATE `visit_count` SET visitCount = visitCount + 1, cookieId = '$sid',   last_visit='$idag' WHERE cookieId = '$sid' AND ipaddress = '$ip'" and MINUTES(last_visit)=MINUTES(TIMESTAMP())-30);
```

It may help you.there may be some syntax error. Internet is creating problem here. optimise syntax error from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html

Comment: +1 for providing the only sensible answer, even if syntax might be wrong, the principle is what matters.

Comment: @N.B. thanks. from my side http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html this site is not opening

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if((time()-1800) > strtotime($row['last_visit']) { // 3600 is one hour, so 1800 is 30 minutes
```

Comment: Why is this not suitable for you? What does "This doesn't update every if the time has passed" mean?